Sidebase Nuxt-auth / Auth.js capturing adapter errors
I'm using sidebase/nuxt-auth as my auth module (based on auth.js) and @auth/pg-adapter as database adapter for a Nuxt3 project.
Everything is working fine when my database server is up. But sometimes it is slow or not available and I receive the following error in my console:
[next-auth][error][adapter_error_getSessionAndUser] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#adapter_error_getsessionanduser connect ETIMEDOUT xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5432 {
  message: 'connect ETIMEDOUT xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5432',
  stack: 'Error: connect ETIMEDOUT xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5432\n' +
    '    at /Users/xxx/node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:45:11\n' +
    '    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n' +
    '    at async getSessionAndUser (file:///Users/xxx/node_modules/@auth/pg-adapter/index.js:248:29)',
  name: 'Error'
}

I'd like to capture the error ideally before it gets thrown (or after if no other solution) to display a custom error message to my customers. As #auth module is running as internal middleware, I can't edit it directly (it is a node_module).
My server side api/auth/[...].js file looks like that:
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook";
import LinkedInProvider from "next-auth/providers/linkedin";
import EmailProvider from "next-auth/providers/email";
import PostgresAdapter from "@auth/pg-adapter"
import { NuxtAuthHandler } from '#auth'
import { createTransport } from "nodemailer"
import pg from 'pg'

const config = useRuntimeConfig();

const { Pool } = pg

const pool = new Pool({
  user: config.private.PG_USER,
  password: config.private.PG_PASSWORD + "r",
  host: config.private.PG_HOST,
  port: 5432,
  database: 'accounts'
})

export default NuxtAuthHandler({
  // A secret string you define, to ensure correct encryption
  secret: 'xxx',
  pages: {
    // Change the default behavior to use `/login` as the path for the sign-in page
    signIn: '/pro',
  },
  session: {
    maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60,
  },
  providers: [
    FacebookProvider.default({
      clientId: config.private.FACEBOOK_ID,
      clientSecret: config.private.FACEBOOK_SECRET,
      allowDangerousEmailAccountLinking: true
    }),
    GoogleProvider.default({
      clientId: config.private.GOOGLE_LOGIN_ID,
      clientSecret: config.private.GOOGLE_LOGIN_SECRET,
      allowDangerousEmailAccountLinking: true
    }),
    LinkedInProvider.default({
      clientId: config.private.LINKEDIN_ID,
      clientSecret: config.private.LINKEDIN_SECRET,
      allowDangerousEmailAccountLinking: true
    }),
    
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      session.user = user
      return session;
    }
  },
  adapter: PostgresAdapter(pool),
})

Is there a way to capture & handle adapter errors with sidebase/Nuxt-auth?
Thanks a lot!
Alex
